# How to Recover a deleted file on github that was not in my local repository

Tags: github

I had a very long Readme.md file in [Github](https://github.com) that I created it directly from the Github website. I was about to pull that to my local repository but unfortunately during a recent commit using eclipse clicked the force update checkbox and deleted that Readme.md from Github!

Now the problem is I did not have that file in my local repository so I don't have so much hope because my local git never had that file to ask him bring it back.
I already tried Google cache but it was a stale version of that :-/
Do you think is there a way that I did not think of to bring it back?

Thank you in advance

Edit:

I also tried to see if I can execute git commands directly in github but could not find anything usefull

Comment: Well if you hadn't have it locally and did a push force there is not possibility to recover it back I guess.

Comment: Yeah, I think so. I don't know why when miss somethings you did not care much, turn to be the most important things in the life, But after sometime, it does not matter again ;)

Comment: We are still talking about git right? ;)